# Drag to rotate an SVG:g group

Tags: html, svg, rotation, d3.js, transform

My goal is to have an `svg:ellipse` with four control points that you can use to resize and rotate. My code works fine if the rotation transform is applied to the ellipse itself, but I want to apply the rotation to a container `svg:g` so that the control points rotate simultaneously without lots of extra code. When I apply the transform to the group, the rotation misbehaves I assume because I'm not thinking of the transformed coordinates properly.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/PbKYn/3/

Notice that the angle flickers between a positive and negative value near beginning of the rotation and that a 2pi rotation of the mouse only rotates the shape 1pi. (I don't think my `angleBetweenPoints` function is wrong though, because if I apply the rotation to the `<ellipse>` and not the `<g>`, the rotation is perfect.)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks-

Comment: If I click on one of the handles and try to rotate the whole ellipse for 360° i doesn't follow the whole way. Do you want this?

Comment: @philipp no, that's one of the bugs, in addition to the flicker around 0 degrees. The clicked control point should stay under the mouse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PbKYn/5/

The fix was changing the rotation angle from `angleBetweenPoints` to `currentAngle + angleBetweenPoints` (pseudo). I think that means that after the rotation is applied, the coordinates were also transformed such that `angleBetweenPoints` was essentially giving `dTheta` instead of `theta`. Le sigh.